# Question on substitution

Tags: first-order-logic, substitution

The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)#First-order_logic) on substitution states:

> In first-order logic, a substitution is a total mapping $σ: V → T$ from variables to terms; many, but not all authors additionally require $σ(x) = x$ for all but finitely many variables $x$.

I really didn't understand the $\sigma(x)=x$ requirement. Does it mean that all variables that occur in the formula, the substitution is applied to, are substituted by themselves, if they are not in the domain of the substitution?

Comment: The _all but finitely many_ part is crucial to understanding this requirement.

Comment: Nitpicking issue... basically a *substitution* is something that we perform on a formula and a formula is a finite expression; thus, only a finite number of variables can occurs in it.